# Select every nth element from an array in julia

Tags: indexing, julia

Let's say have an array `a` and I want every other element. With `numpy`, I would use `a[::2]`. How can I do the same in julia?

Answer (score 17):

It is similar to python where elements are selected using `start:stop[:step]` but in julia it's `start:[step:]stop`, so if all three arguments are given, `step` and `stop` have opposite meaning. See the [docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/math/#Base.::) on `:` or `colon`

For example

```
julia> a = randn(20);

julia> a[1:2:end]
10-element Vector{Float64}:
...

julia> a[begin:2:end] # equivalent for default one-based indexing
10-element Vector{Float64}:
...

julia> a[1:5:end]
4-element Vector{Float64}:
 ...
```

But ignoring the bounds won't work as in python because `:` has several meanings in julia

```
julia> a[::2]
ERROR: syntax: invalid "::" syntax

julia> a[:2:]
ERROR: syntax: missing last argument in ":(2):" range expression

julia> a[2::]
ERROR: syntax: unexpected "]"

julia> a[:2:end] # `:2` is a `Symbol` and evaluates to `2`, so start from 2nd element
19-element Vector{Float64}:
  ...
```

Comment: Should mentioned that this is the same as MATLAB's notation.

Comment: I think the link to the `:`/`colon`-documentation has moved to here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/math/#Base.::

Comment: fixed in the answer

Comment: This answer should probably highlight `begin` as well.